The unit test on requests v2.28.2 failed while testing def test_chunked_upload()
Python version : 3.9.6
def test_chunked_upload():
"""can safely send generators"""
 close_server = threading.Event()
 server = Server.basic_response_server(wait_to_close_event=close_server)
 data = iter([b"a", b"b", b"c"])

 with server as (host, port):
 url = f"http://{host}:{port}/"
 r = requests.post(url, data=data, stream=True)
 close_server.set()  # release server block

 >       assert r.status_code == 200
 E       assert 502 == 200
 E        +  where 502 = <Response [502]>.status_code
 
 tests/test_lowlevel.py:35: AssertionError


Build command : python3 -u -m build -w
Test command : tox -e py39-default
I was building it in a docker container.
Can someone please point out why is this happening?
